# Using transformer in simulation software

Tags: transformer, proteus

[image]

I am trying to simulate a transformer in Proteus. But the following are some of the parameters I am unable to understand.

1. Trace Inductance.

[Advanced Properties].

2. Max Permeability.
3. Saturation Permeability.

Please also share experience regarding the design of transformer in simulation to reality in performance and accuracy wise.

Comment: Research [transformers](https://www.pulseelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Introduction-Transformer-Magnetics.pdf) and [Saturable Core Transformer models](http://www.intusoft.com/articles/satcore.pdf) to learn about core properties such as permeability and simulating a saturable core.  Trace inductance (from the traces connected to the transformer) is just added to the leakage inductance.

Comment: @rdtsc "Saturable Core Transformer models", very useful.thanks

Comment: Is Saturation Inductance is the inductance when material permeability is unity?